# Can I implement my own view resolution service and have RequestNavigate use it?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, prism-4

I 'm fairly new to Prism and I 'm currently re-writing one of our existing applications using Prism as a proof of concept project.

The application uses MVVM with a ViewModel first approach: our ViewModel is resolved by the container, and an `IViewResolver` service figures out what view it should be wired up to (using name conventions amongst other things).

The code (to add a view to a tab control) at the moment looks something like this:

```
var vm = (get ViewModel from somewhere)
IRegion reg = _regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"];
var vw = _viewResolver.FromViewModel(vm); // Spins up a view and sets its DataContext
reg.Add(vw);
reg.Activate(vw);
```

This all works fine, however I 'd really like to use the Prism navigation framework to do all this stuff for me so that I can do something like this:

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(
    "MainRegion", 
    new Uri("NameOfMyViewModel", UriKind.Relative)
);
```

and have Prism spin up the ViewModel + View, set up the DataContext and insert the view into the region.

I 've had some success by creating DataTemplates referencing the ViewModel types, e.g.:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Module01">
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestViewModel}">
<local:TestView />
</DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

...and have the module add the relevant resource dictionary into the applications resources when the module is initialized, but that seems a bit rubbish.

Is there a way to effectively take over view creation from Prism, so that when `RequestNavigate` is called I can look at the supplied `Uri` and spin up the view / viewmodel based on that? There’s an overload of `RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion` that takes a delegate that allows you to supply a view yourself, and I guess I’m after something like that.

I think I might need to supply my own `IRegionBehaviorFactory`, but am unsure what's involved (or even if I am on the right path!).

Any help appreciated!

--
note: Originally posted over at [the prism codeplex site](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/272848)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure you can do that. I 've found that Prism v4 is really extensible, if only you know where to plug in.

In this case, you want your own custom implementation of [`IRegionNavigationContentLoader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.iregionnavigationcontentloader%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx).

Here's how to set things up in your bootstrapper (the example is from a subclass of `UnityBootstrapper` from one of my own projects):

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    // IMPORTANT: Due to the inner workings of UnityBootstrapper, accessing
    // ServiceLocator.Current here will throw an exception!
    // If you want access to IServiceLocator, resolve it from the container directly.
    base.ConfigureContainer();

    // Set up our own content loader, passing it a reference to the service locator
    // (it will need this to resolve ViewModels from the container automatically)
    this.Container.RegisterInstance<IRegionNavigationContentLoader>(
       new ViewModelContentLoader(this.Container.Resolve<IServiceLocator>()));
}
```

The `ViewModelContentLoader` itself derives from [`RegionNavigationContentLoader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.regionnavigationcontentloader%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx) to reuse code, and will look something like this:

```
public class ViewModelContentLoader : RegionNavigationContentLoader
{
    private readonly IServiceLocator serviceLocator;

    public ViewModelContentLoader(IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
        : base(serviceLocator)
    {
        this.serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
    }

    // THIS IS CALLED WHEN A NEW VIEW NEEDS TO BE CREATED
    // TO SATISFY A NAVIGATION REQUEST
    protected override object CreateNewRegionItem(string candidateTargetContract)
    {
        // candidateTargetContract is e.g. "NameOfMyViewModel"

        // Just a suggestion, plug in your own resolution code as you see fit
        var viewModelType = this.GetTypeFromName(candidateTargetContract);
        var viewModel = this.serviceLocator.GetInstance(viewModelType);

        // get ref to viewResolver somehow -- perhaps from the container?
        var view = _viewResolver.FromViewModel(vm);

        return view;
    }

    // THIS IS CALLED TO DETERMINE IF THERE IS ANY EXISTING VIEW
    // THAT CAN SATISFY A NAVIGATION REQUEST
    protected override IEnumerable<object> 
    GetCandidatesFromRegion(IRegion region, string candidateNavigationContract)
    {
        if (region == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("region");
        }

        // Just a suggestion, plug in your own resolution code as you see fit
        var viewModelType = this.GetTypeFromName(candidateNavigationContract);

        return region.Views.Where(v =>
            ViewHasDataContract((FrameworkElement)v, viewModelType) ||
            string.Equals(v.GetType().Name, candidateNavigationContract, StringComparison.Ordinal) ||
            string.Equals(v.GetType().FullName, candidateNavigationContract, StringComparison.Ordinal));
    }

    // USED IN MY IMPLEMENTATION OF GetCandidatesFromRegion
    private static bool 
    ViewHasDataContract(FrameworkElement view, Type viewModelType)
    {
        var dataContextType = view.DataContext.GetType();

        return viewModelType.IsInterface
           ? dataContextType.Implements(viewModelType)
           : dataContextType == viewModelType 
                   || dataContextType.GetAncestors().Any(t => t == viewModelType);
    }

    // USED TO MAP STRINGS OF VIEWMODEL TYPE NAMES TO ACTUAL TYPES
    private Type GetTypeFromName(string typeName)
    {
        // here you need to map the string type to a Type object, e.g.
        // "NameOfMyViewModel" => typeof(NameOfMyViewModel)

        return typeof(NameOfMyViewModel); // hardcoded for simplicity
    }
}
```

Comment: That's actually perfect! Thanks! - Pj

Answer (score 2):

To stop some confusion about "ViewModel first approach": 
You use more a "controller approach", but no "ViewModel first approach". A "ViewModel first approach" is, when you inject your View in your ViewModel, but you wire up both, your ViewModel and View, through a third party component (a controller), what by the way is the (I dont want to say "best", but) most loosely coupled approach.

But to answer your Question:
A possible solution is to write an Extension for the Prism RegionManager that does exactly what you have described above:

```cs
    public static class RegionManagerExtensions
    {            
        public static void AddToRegion<TViewModel>(
               this IRegionManager regionManager, string region)
        {
            var viewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<TViewModel>();
            FrameworkElement view;

            // Get View depending on your conventions

            if (view == null) throw new NullReferenceException("View not found.");

            view.DataContext = viewModel;
            regionManager.AddToRegion(region, view);
            regionManager.Regions[region].Activate(view);

        }
    }
```

then you can call this method like this:

```cs
regionManager.AddToRegion<IMyViewModel>("MyRegion");
```

Comment: Isn't that pretty much exactly what I'm doing in my original example though? - What I'm after is a way to override / influence how the navigation api (ie, RequestNavigate()) resolves view instances from a Uri

Comment: I've edited the question slightly to hopefully make it clearer!